# Suggested new tag: in-universe-explanation

Tags: discussion, tags

I'd like to suggest a new tag: **in-universe-explanation**

There seem to be a lot of questions asking for an in-universe explanation as to why something happened. I think this could cover a lot of questions.

Before I started retagging questions, I'd like to check whether this community thinks it is a good idea, and if they'd be willing to help add this tag to existing questions and new ones as they arrive.

*Examples*

1. [There is always an exterior light shining onto the ship in every Star Trek; where does this light source come from?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4820)
2. [What keeps a lightsaber from going on infinitely?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4845)
3. [Where does Q technology come from and where did it orginate?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3172)
4. [What happened to Optimus Prime's trailer when he transformed into a robot?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4659) - *I added it to this question of mine*

Comment: This seems like a meta-tag to me. Why would someone wish to subscribe to this tag?

Comment: @All: [here is a link about meta-tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) since I had to look it up myself.

Comment: @DampeS8N: I don't think it is a meta-tag. Looking at the above link: 1. it's not *subjective*, 2. it does *describe* the *content* 3. it wouldn't be used *on its own* (e.g. additional tag might be *star-trek*) 4. it doesn't *mean different things to different people*.

Comment: being used on its own is a good thing. "If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag."

Comment: I'm not sure there's any need for such a tag. Questions asking for in-universe explanations either ask for speculation rather than a documented answer (in which case they shouldn't be allowed at all), or can easily be rephrased to not be in-universe ("Is there any evidence in the body of canonical works for this universe regarding X").

Comment: It already exists, see [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/in-universe-explanation) ...

Comment: @takrl - true, because anyone over a certain rep can create it on Beta. I wanted to see if there was enthusiasm for using it - judging by the votes it seems not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would there be a tag for in-universe explanations? Most questions don't specifically call for an in-universe or a meta explanation, so the answers give both. Either all the questions that ask for some kind of in-universe explanation should have it (too much), or only the questions that exclusively require in-universe explanations should have it (useless).

I can see that a tag for questions that call for some in-universe explanation could be useful in searches, and ditto for a tag for meta explanations. However, since many questions gather answers with some of both (I think, I haven't made any statistics), there wouldn't be many questions without these tags (except when someone forgot to put them in). So they wouldn't carry much useful information.

So, no, I don't see the point: it's useless if applied properly, and useless if not applied properly.

Comment: In addition, I think it's established (but I can't recall in which meta question right now) that the default position is to assume that questions want an in-universe answer.

Comment: @TonyMeyer - Precisely. And where an out-of-universe answer is supplied, it needs to be far more insightful than simply *"because the writer wrote it that way"*.